# read data from file and store in array in c++

Tags: c++

I am hoping and wondering if someone can help me understand how to do the following in C++:
**Use command line input-redirection to store the contents of a file into a 2-d array.**

The files will have an unknown number of lines with 3 columns.
Something like this:
20 42 0.00
15 67 2.41
70 53 9.88

So an array needs to be made that can hold x number of arrays. X being the number of lines in the file. Each interior-array will hold one of the columns of the line.

I have no idea how to do this, but I would sincerely appreciate any and all help and direction in how to do so.

Thanks in Advance & Best Regards!

Comment: What exactly you don't know how to do? How to read from file? How to put into an array? How to use command line input redirection?

Comment: @amit Well, one would put the contents into the array using a for loop , right? The rest I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like homework here are a few basic hints.

You can direct the output of one command as the input of another using pipes like:

```
cat myfile.txt | myprogram
```

`myprogram` can then read the data using `cin`.

That should be enough to get your started.

Answer (score 0):

```
static const size_t START_SIZE = 100;

//allocate array of pointers
double** flt_arr = new double*[START_SIZE];

size_t current_size = START_SIZE;
size_t current_index = 0;

while (!cin.eof())
{
    double flt1, flt2, flt3;

    cin >> flt1 >> flt2 >> flt3;

    //check stream for bad read
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Input error on line " << current_index + 1 << "!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    if (current_size == current_index)
    {
        //grow array
        current_size += START_SIZE;

        double** tmp_arr = new double*[current_size];

        for (size_t count = 0; count < current_index; count++)
        {
            tmp_arr[count] = flt_arr[count];
        }

        delete [] flt_arr;
        flt_arr = tmp_arr;
    }

    //allocate row for current line
    flt_arr[current_index] = new double[3];

    flt_arr[current_index][0] = flt1;
    flt_arr[current_index][1] = flt2;
    flt_arr[current_index][2] = flt3;

    current_index++;
}

//clean up rows
for (size_t count = 0; count < current_index; count++)
{
    delete [] flt_arr[count];
}

//clean up array of pointers
delete [] flt_arr;
```